# Can I style an image's ALT text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a dark blue page and when the image is loading (or missing) the ALT text is black and difficult to read (in FF).

Could I style it (with CSS) to be white?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Setting the `img` tag `color` works

```
img {color:#fff}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YEkAt/

```css
body {background:#000022}
img {color:#fff}
```

```html
<img src="http://badsrc.com/blah" alt="BLAH BLAH BLAH" />
```

Comment: I used to do this when I was like 9 with `<font color="#FFFFFF"><img ...></font>`. Man those were the days.

Answer (score 17):

Sure you can!

http://jsfiddle.net/VfTGW/

I do this as a fallback for header logo images, I think some versions of IE will not abide. **Edit**: Or Chrome apparently - I don't even *see* alt text in the demo(?). Firefox works well however.

```css
img {
  color: green;
  font: 40px Impact;
}
```

```html
<img src="404" alt="Alt Text">
```

Comment: As of 2018, I'm seeing it fine in Chrome too. One thing I notice is that text-decoration isn't applicable in any browser I've checked.

Answer (score 5):

You cant style the alt attribute directly in css. However the alt will inherit the styles of the item the alt is on or what is inherited by its parent:

```html
    <div style="background-color:black; height: 50px; width: 50px; color:white;">
    <img src="ouch" alt="here i am"/>
    <div>
```

In the above example, the alt text will be black. However with the color:white the alt text is white.

Answer (score 4):

as this question is the first result at search engines

There are a problem with the selected -and right by the way- solution, is that if you want to add style that will apply to images like ( borders for example ) .

for example :

```css
img {
  color:#fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://badsrc.com/blah" alt="BLAH BLAH BLAH" /> <hr />
<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-square-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-square-social-media-128.png" alt="BLAH BLAH BLAH" />
```

as you can see, all of images will apply the same style

---

there is another approach to easily work around such an issue, using `onerror` and injecting some special class to deal with the interrupted images :

```css
.invalidImageSrc {
  color:#fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img onerror="$(this).addClass('invalidImageSrc')" src="http://badsrc.com/blah" alt="BLAH BLAH BLAH" /> <hr />
<img onerror="$(this).addClass('invalidImageSrc')" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-square-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-square-social-media-128.png" alt="BLAH BLAH BLAH" />
```

Comment: does the OP had asked for a 'pure' css solution ?

Comment: also do you see that I had mentioned that's my solution is a work-around ?

Comment: why not ? for sure someone on the planet will make a use of your alternative solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox and Chrome (and possibly more) we can insert the string ‘( .... )’ into the alt text of an image that hasn’t loaded.

```css
img {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #c00;
}

img:after {
  content: " (Image - Right click to reload if not loaded)";
}

img::after {
  content: " (Image - Right click to reload if not loaded)";
}
```

```html
<img alt="Alt text - " />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, image alt text can be styled using any style property you use for regular text, such as font-size, font-weight, line-height, color, background-color,etc. The line-height (of text) or vertical-align (if display:table-cell used) could also be used to vertically align alt text within an image element or image wrapping container, i.e. div.

To prevent accessibility issues regarding contrast, and inheriting the browser's default black font color when you've set a dark blue background-color, always set both the color of your font and its background-color at the same time.

for some more useful info, visit [Alternate text for background images](https://www.davidmacd.com/blog/alternate-text-for-css-background-images.html) or [The Ultimate Guide to Styled ALT Text in Email](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-styled-alt-text-in-email/)

Answer (score -3):

You can use `img[alt] {styles}` to style only the alternative text.

Comment: This does not focus on the alternative text, but instead on any image element that contains alt-attribute.

Comment: You can use a class on image or a regular expression on src to target the specific image. Simple css my friend.

Comment: katsampu, the original question asked about targeting the alt text, In your answer you are talking about "style only the alternative text". This statement is incorrect. This does not target the text, but the image element around it. If I set img[alt]{border:1px solid red;padding:10px;} those changes effect the image itself, not the alt text. Some changes may be inherited into the alt text too (depending on browser implementation). But it does not only style the alt text like you said. It styles only image elements that have alt text attribute. See the difference?